# How to change value of select input which is inside a form balise (ant design)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm searching how to change the value of my select input inside of a form balise (with ant design library).

```
 let [value, setValue] = useState(null)
```

```
<Form.Item name="value" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Veuillez choisir une valeur !' }]}
                   label="Type">
     <Select value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e)}>
         <Option value="pp">Personne physique</Option>
         <Option value="mp">Personne morale</Option>
     </Select>
</Form.Item>

<Button type="primary" onClick={setValue('pp')}>Click me</Button>
```

When i'm clicking, nothing happen, the value stay the old one.

But if I delete the `<Form.Item>` balise, it work correctly.

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: why you need that ant design to manage well when you submit form.

Comment: Can you add your code to an online editor, please ? I don't understand how that work with `setValue(e)` if you delete `<Form.Item>`, thnx

Comment: @Nokwiw This is my exemple : https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-zeh-esxtc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Kantivekariya I follow the project structure, it work correctly for everything but not in my case

Comment: @Nokwiw This is when it work (without Form.item) : https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-khorana-vynvt?file=/src/App.js:102-106

Comment: take a look that work for me, look to the console https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-murdock-ikcgp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Andy can you pls check this I will manage the same case in my projects[here](https://github.com/kantivekariya/react_quiz/blob/master/quiz/src/registration/Registration.jsx)

Comment: @Nokwiw Your solution doesn't work, it doesn't set the value of the select input. It just print the value on the console

Comment: @Andy I made for you a working example using ant design form let me know if you need more help https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-snow-3tlr8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Kantivekariya It doesn't work in my side. It change the value on the field in your case ?

Comment: it' working you can also see a log inside `handleFormValuesChange` this function, check I added the code of the snippet below.

Comment: I have checked and your solution doesn't work. I send a link where it work. 
( codesandbox.io/s/cocky-khorana-vynvt?file=/src/App.js:102-106 ).
I need that it work like this with <form.item>

Comment: @Andy check now updated you not need to `useState` ant design provides some future use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237179/discussion-between-andy-and-kanti-vekariya).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this

```
let [value, setValue] = useState(null)

const handleFormValuesChange = (changedValues) => {
  const formFieldName = Object.keys(changedValues)[0];
  if (formFieldName === "typeCeso") {
    setValue(changedValues[formFieldName]);
  }
};



<Form form={form} name="form" onFinish={onFinish} onValuesChange={handleFormValuesChange}>
  <Form.Item
  name="typeCeso"
  rules={[{ required: true, message: "Veuillez choisir une valeur !" }]}
  label="Type"
>
  <Select>
    <Option value="pp">Personne physique</Option>
    <Option value="mp">Personne morale</Option>
  </Select>
</Form.Item>
</Form>
```